# Running a full node without revealing my home IP address

Tags: i2p, tor, vps, vpn

How can I safely run a full node without revealing my home IP address?

Please compare the privacy and security of the following methods for running a Monero node both from home and by using a cloud based VPS:

1. Tor
2. I2P
3. VPN

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can only speak for Tor: using `torsocks` can make `monerod` connect to other nodes via the Tor network.

This will run `monerod` with Tor:

```
DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd
```

If you cannot connect your wallet (which should not use Tor), you may need to add `TORSOCKS_ALLOW_INBOUND`. Apparently, different systems may or may not need this option:

```
DNS_PUBLIC=tcp TORSOCKS_ALLOW_INBOUND=1 torsocks monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd
```

In any case, make sure your firewall blocks the port `monerod` may listen for RPC connections, assuming the wallet runs locally.

Comment: "In any case, make sure your firewall blocks the port bitmonerod may listen for RPC connections, assuming the wallet runs locally." Could you expand on this? I mean, using Torsocks is not enough for protecting the IP? How is listening for RPC connections compromising the security? How does one go about blocking that port? Is it blocked by default? Etc.

Comment: For the latest version, replace all instances of bitmonerod with monerod

Comment: How would one go about running this in the background?