# Is it possible to set the GUI to run over Torsocks?

Tags: tor, monero-wallet-gui

Hopefully this will be possible and made easy for the user, perhaps with the click of a button?

Comment: I agree. It should be built in. Even surveillance friendly Bitcoin has Socks5 compatibility built in.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly configure Torsocks in the GUI at the time of writing. However, you can run `monerod` and connect the GUI to your local daemon.

Set the daemon to connect to Tor. [Use the guide here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/556/42).