# What is the difference between Monero (XMR) and Nav Coin (NAV)?

Tags: privacy, cryptocurrency-comparison

Can someone please compare the privacy differences comparing Monero vs Nav Coin? I have heard that each addresses privacy using different methods, and I am interested in what they do differently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Despite both being advertised as privacy-focused cryptocurrencies, they are very different.

**Monero** uses [ring signatures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHN_B_H_fCs), [RingCT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3AHp9KgTkQ), and [stealth addresses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWst278J8NA) to hide information on the blockchain. For every transaction, there is no way for an outside observer to determine the sending address, the amount sent, or the receiving address. Optional transparency can be provided *off-chain* by giving the desired person(s) the view key. [Monero can be used with Tor](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/467/running-a-full-node-without-revealing-my-home-ip-address) or I2P manually, and [Kovri](https://getkovir.org) is being worked on to provide native anonymous routing functionality.

**Nav Coin** uses [trusted clustered servers](https://www.navcoin.org/files/navtech-whitepaper-beta-v0.9.pdf) to process transactions. When the "anonymous" option is selected, transactions are sent to these servers, which conceal the recipient address from others. It does not protect the sender, it does not hide the amount, and there is a trusted party that is omniscient in this process.

---

In summary, Monero protects significantly more information about all transactions (not just a select few) without using a trusted party.